# How to us Conditional Formatting with color scale based on data in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

need some help with conditional formatting. Take a look at the sheet below. I would like to apply conditional formatting to D20 based on the vales of C20. For example, I want it to be on a color scale with the midpoint being the value in C20 and the min value be 2% and the max value be 2%. So if the value in D20 is higher than C20 it is a red shad and lower than C20 a green shade. I want it to be a percentage so that I can copy and paste it to other months and cells.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RVL9dfjjYwl-7Ke7dM1dUJNecieGvlvFBJUXmn9U8Cw/edit#gid=0&range=A1

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a column of colors (in your file A8: A17) and then conditional format it together with cell D20, as in this picture:

[image: conditional]

The cell A8 will have the formula:

```
= sequence (10,1,0, C20 / 5)
```

See your modified file